# How can I get the attributes from a mysql table by specific column?

Tags: php, mysql

I have run a query `DESCRIBE employee` and got the table information like this

```
Field            Type            Key        Extra
==========================================================
employee_id      int(10)         PRI        auto_increment              
contact_number   varchar(20)     UNI                        
department_id    int(10)         MUL                        
designation_id   int(10)         MUL
```

How or in which query I get the attributes where Field='contact_number'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
DESCRIBE employee contact_number
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Field            Type            Key        Extra
==========================================================           
contact_number   varchar(20)     UNI
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search specific column among all databases, use following query,

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE  FROM COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'contact_number' ;
```

You also can filter table and schema if needed, using where clause.